# How to trigger a keypress with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, keypress

I am trying to get a key to be pressed, in this case NumPad0, or Alt, or PageUp, or PageDown, or a combination like Ctrl+A, when an HTML button is clicked, based on its ID.

For example,

```
<button id="myButton">Button</button>
```

When button is clicked,

```
function simulateClick(id) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    clickEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        false, false, false, false, 0, null);

    var element = document.getElementById('myButton');
    element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'PageDown'}));
}
```

However, nothing happens when I click.

Ultimately the goal is to run an autohotkey script which is bound to certain keys and key combos so that effectively, clicking a button will simply run that portion of the autohotkey script as if I had pressed the keyboard button.

I saw how to do it with jquery, but I need to use pure js. How can I trigger a keypress with pure javascript?

Comment: JQuery Is open source. You can inspect what happens behind the scenes by digging into the internals

Comment: Do you mean you want to progromatically trigger the key being pressed in JavaScript, i.e. "press the key for the user". If this is the case, you cannot do this in JavaScript, for obvious security reasons...

Comment: Do you really need to trigger a `keypress` or just simply call the handler that actually pressing the key(s) would have called?

Comment: As per @Enijar, JavaScript cannot send OS level key events to the browser.

Comment: @ScottMarcus whichever solution will work best for triggering an AutoHotKey script which looks for a key press.

Comment: Then all you need to do is call the function you need executed upon the button `click`. That's it. No need to raise events.

Comment: @ScottMarcus How do you do that?

Comment: Look at the function that you have for handling the regular button click event. Then, when you need that code executed, just call that function (i.e. `functionName()`).

Comment: @ScottMarcus I don't have a function for a click event and I don't know how to do it. How about post an answer and I can try it and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate a key press, you are on the right track.

Add the event that you want to simulate to the document/element first then you can add a click listener to the button to fire that event you are listening to.

Firing the key event wont actually scroll the document for you, you will need a way to programatically scroll the page. This article, titled [*"Page scrolling in vanilla JavaScript"*](https://pawelgrzybek.com/page-scroll-in-vanilla-javascript/), has a function that simulate scrolling. I have adapted it below. I made it scroll 25% of the document height at a time. The <kbd>Page Down</kbd> button varies as to how much of the document is scrolled though.

Note that the author updated their post to indicate that there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) for `window.scroll` available that may work better.

```js
const AUTO_SCROLL = false

const btn = document.querySelector('#my-button')
const ara = document.querySelector('#my-textarea')

document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyPress)
btn.addEventListener('click', simulateClick)

function onKeyPress(e) {
  if (e.key === 'PageDown') {
    ara.value += 'DOWN\n'
  }
}

function simulateClick(e) {
  // Scroll the document
  if (AUTO_SCROLL) {
    const documentHeight = Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight,
      document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight,
      document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight);
    scrollIt(window.pageYOffset + (documentHeight * 0.25))
  }
  // Fire the event to handle the rest...
  document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    key: 'PageDown'
  }))
}

/** Source: https://pawelgrzybek.com/page-scroll-in-vanilla-javascript/ */
function scrollIt(destination, duration = 200, easing = 'linear', callback) {
  const easings = {
    linear(t) {
      return t;
    },
    easeInQuad(t) {
      return t * t;
    },
    easeOutQuad(t) {
      return t * (2 - t);
    },
    easeInOutQuad(t) {
      return t < 0.5 ? 2 * t * t : -1 + (4 - 2 * t) * t;
    },
    easeInCubic(t) {
      return t * t * t;
    },
    easeOutCubic(t) {
      return (--t) * t * t + 1;
    },
    easeInOutCubic(t) {
      return t < 0.5 ? 4 * t * t * t : (t - 1) * (2 * t - 2) * (2 * t - 2) + 1;
    },
    easeInQuart(t) {
      return t * t * t * t;
    },
    easeOutQuart(t) {
      return 1 - (--t) * t * t * t;
    },
    easeInOutQuart(t) {
      return t < 0.5 ? 8 * t * t * t * t : 1 - 8 * (--t) * t * t * t;
    },
    easeInQuint(t) {
      return t * t * t * t * t;
    },
    easeOutQuint(t) {
      return 1 + (--t) * t * t * t * t;
    },
    easeInOutQuint(t) {
      return t < 0.5 ? 16 * t * t * t * t * t : 1 + 16 * (--t) * t * t * t * t;
    }
  };

  const start = window.pageYOffset;
  const startTime = 'now' in window.performance
    ? performance.now() : new Date().getTime();

  const documentHeight = Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight,
    document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight,
    document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight);
  const windowHeight = window.innerHeight ||
    document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
  const destOffset = typeof destination === 'number'
    ? destination : destination.offsetTop;
  const destOffScroll = Math.round(documentHeight - destOffset < windowHeight
    ? documentHeight - windowHeight : destOffset);

  if ('requestAnimationFrame' in window === false) {
    window.scroll(0, destOffScroll);
    if (callback) {
      callback();
    }
    return;
  }

  function scroll() {
    const now = 'now' in window.performance ? performance.now() : new Date().getTime();
    const time = Math.min(1, ((now - startTime) / duration));
    const timeFunction = easings[easing](time);
    window.scroll(0, Math.ceil((timeFunction * (destOffScroll - start)) + start));

    if (window.pageYOffset === destOffScroll) {
      if (callback) {
        callback();
      }
      return;
    }
    
    requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
  }

  scroll();
}
```

```css
#my-button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 4em;
  top: 1.33em;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="my-textarea" rows="100" cols="62"></textarea>
<button id="my-button">Button</button>
```

Comment: Please note that I do not want to do any scrolling. I want to be able to select specific keys to be pressed so that autohotkey will pick it up as a keypress and run the respective script. For example, I chose PageDown key which is rarely used, to be assigned to a macro. If I can get a keypress fired once clicking an on-page button, then I should be able to achieve my objective.

Comment: @coder9328 If you do not want the programmatic scrolling, then just leave that part out. The event still fires as intended.

Comment: I'm not sure what to leave out. Can you update or append your answer with what I would need in order to only fire the key event on button click? Thanks.

Comment: @coder9328 I wrapped the code you can remove in an `AUTO_SCROLL` flag. The code inside that condition can be left out. Along with the entire `scrollIt` function declaration. I defaulted it to `false` so that it does not actually do the scrolling.

Comment: That actually makes it far more complicated. It would be easier for you to append so two answers - one with scrolling and one without.

Comment: I wish I had a solution to this problem.